# Change Scala code to send grouped data based on email from two different Array Records

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have two tables one Records and one called Identifier here:

```
val finalResultsRecords: Array[Records] = 
  sqlContext.sql("select * from Records").as[Records].collect()


val finalResultsIdentifier: Array[Identifier] = 
  sqlContext.sql("select * from Identifier").as[Identifier].collect()
```

Currently I send these as two separate emails to the individual specified email:

```
finalResultsRecords.groupBy(_.email).foreach { case (email, finalResultsRecords) =>
  val HTMLTableOfRecords: String = generateReport(finalResultsRecords)
  var emailContent : String = "$HTMLTableOfRecords";
  sendEmail(s"EXAMPLE RECORDS",emailContent, List(email))
}
```

and then the Identifier results here:

```
finalResultsIdentifier.groupBy(_.email).foreach { case (email, finalResultsIdentifier) =>
  val HTMLTableOfIdentifiers: String = generateReport2(finalResultsIdentifier)
  var emailContent : String = "$HTMLTableOfIdentifiers";
  sendEmail(s"EXAMPLE IDENTIFIERS",emailContent, List(email))
}
```

How can I merge this to make it smarter where if the emails match send them as one email rather than two separate emails to people. So for example from Records if we have email1@email.com and in Identifier we have email1@email.com send out the email content as

```
  var emailContent : String = "$HTMLTableOfIdentifiers + $HTMLTableOfRecords";
```

If the email is found in Records send out the email content as :

```
  var emailContent : String = "$HTMLTableOfRecords";
```

If the email is found in Identifiers send out the email content as :

```
  var emailContent : String = "$HTMLTableOfIdentifiers";
```

Edit:

```
    val finalResultsRecords: Array[Records] = sqlContext.sql("select * from Records").as[Records].collect()
    
    val finalResultsIdentifier: Array[Identifier] = sqlContext.sql("select * from Identifier").as[Identifier].collect()
        
    val together: Array[(String, Either[finalResultsRecords, finalResultsIdentifier])] = 
           finalResultsRecords.map(r => (r.email, Left(r))) ++ finalResultsIdentifier.map(r => (r.email, Right(r)))
        
    val toSend: Map[String, String] = together.groupBy(_._1).mapValues{   
           entries => {
             val parts = entries.map(e => e._2 match {
               case Left(rec) => s"Records: ${rec}"
               case Right(ident) => s"Indentifier: ${ident}"
             })
            parts.mkString(",")
           }
         }.toMap
        
toSend.foreach{
          case (address, content) =>  
    
          val HTMLTableOfRecords: String = generateReport(finalResultsRecords)
          val HTMLTableOfIdentifiers: String = generateReport2(finalResultsIdentifier)
        
          var content : String = "";
            content = s"""
            <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
            ${HTMLTableOfRecords}
            <br><br>
            ${HTMLTableOfIdentifiers}
            <br>
            </p>
            <p>
            </p>"""   
    
          sendEmail(s"EXAMPLE IDENTIFIERS",content, List(address))
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to merge records and identifiers into a single structure before calling `groupBy`. E.g.:

```
case class Records(email: String, stuff : String)
case class Identifier(email: String, differentStuff : String)

val records: Seq[Records] = ??? //sqlContext.sql("select * from Records").as[Records].collect()
val identifiers: Seq[Identifier] = ??? // sqlContext.sql("select * from Identifier").as[Identifier].collect()
val together: Seq[(String, Either[Records, Identifier])] = 
  records.map(r => (r.email, Left(r))) ++ identifiers.map(r => (r.email, Right(r)))
val toSend: Map[String, String] = together.groupBy(_._1).mapValues{
  //form email content
  entries => {
    val parts = entries.map(e => e._2 match {
      case Left(rec) => s"records: ${rec.stuff}"
      case Right(ident) => s"identifier: ${ident.differentStuff}"
    })
   parts.mkString(",")
  }
}.toMap

toSend.foreach{
  case (address, content) => ??? //send email
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But Both Records and Identifiers hold different data columns too. From using my code above with finalResultsRecords and finalResultsIdentifiers how can I use this code? Because it seems in the class you have Seq[Data] =???

Comment: I modified the code to accommodate different structure of records and identifiers

Comment: I've added the code above, the way you are using seq won't work as when I generateReport this maps the array data into html (see above). Also the code doesn't work for me

Comment: The code shows how to group data into groups by email. It's not intended to produce well-formed html pages, load data from spark, etc. 
You have to adapt it to your needs. "Doesn't work for me" is not actionable w/o an error message.

Comment: Okay I think I may have got it to work. Im testing it in different cases

Comment: This works if theres one email address, it will send both reports to that email. Issue is where there is multiple emails, I don't want the all the data sent to all emails. Which is why I groupBy(_.email) in my code above. In the toSend method this sends out all data to all emails which I could have done without a groupby or loop. I need the code to only send the relevant data to the relevant emails. Can you please amend the code to do this? I've shown an example of the setup I have above. Thanks

Comment: Additionally you can see from the code above I generate the reports from Arrays, not Strings. The content is returned as a String. This won't work, even without an error message it just won't work for when I generateReport as I use an Array class and map the values into html columns. Can't do that from a String (content)

Comment: `together.groupBy(_._1)` will result in one entry per email. Please check again. Sorry, this discussion doesn't goes into "do it for me" direction and doesn't follow Stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: I understand that but I'm not massively familiar with scala. It's not do it for me, I've been trying to get it to work all day. As you can see from my edited post. I can't get it to work, which is why I put this on a bounty for 200. I would appreciate if you can at least show or explain how with content I can all generateReports to send the emails I need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225637/discussion-between-simpadjo-and-sam).